# Inner select statement not working in view

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a view in TSQL that I am querying with a simple Select TOP 1 from vw_Dates where name = 'test'.

When I hardcode the name as test, in both parts (parts that are commented out), it works, the originalStartDate is populated. When I uncomment those parts, the logic works. How can I get this view to work where the outer select, and the inner select part know to use 'test' when I query this view with "Select TOP 1 from vw_Dates where name = 'test'"

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vw_Dates] AS

SELECT *,
 (CASE
        WHEN originalStartDate < CurrentStartDate THEN originalStartDate
        
        ELSE CurrentStartDate
        END) AS CorrectStartDate 

FROM(
SELECT
 
    CurrentStartDate,   
   (select Top 1 startDate AS oldestStartDate from Dates dt
        where 
        --name = 'test' 
        --and 
        status = 'ACTIVE' order by startDate) AS originalStartDate,
  
 
   
FROM Dates
WHERE Dates.status = 'ACTIVE'
--and
--name = 'test' 

)x
```

Comment: "not working" means what?

Comment: Sample data and expected results would help immensely, as well as an explanation of the logic you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to correlate your sub-query using the `Name` column, and then rather than filtering in the view, filter when you select from the view.

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vw_Dates]
AS
SELECT *
    , CASE
      WHEN originalStartDate < CurrentStartDate THEN originalStartDate        
      ELSE CurrentStartDate
      END AS CorrectStartDate 
FROM (
    SELECT dt.CurrentStartDate,  (
            SELECT TOP 1 dt1.startDate AS oldestStartDate
            FROM dbo.Dates dt1
            WHERE dt1.[Name] = dt.[Name]
            AND dt1.[Status] = dt.[Status]
            ORDER BY dt1.startDate
        ) AS originalStartDate
        , dt.[Name]
    FROM dbo.Dates dt
    WHERE dt.[Status] = 'ACTIVE'
) x;
```

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.vw_Dates
WHERE [Name] = 'Test';
```

Note: I have correlated `Status` as well to avoid typing the same status twice.

And as HoneyBadger points out using `MIN()` is clearer e.g.

```
SELECT MIN(dt1.startDate) AS oldestStartDate
FROM dbo.Dates dt1
WHERE dt1.[Name] = dt.[Name]
AND dt1.[Status] = dt.[Status]
```

Comment: Additionally, `MIN(dt1.startDate)` would be clearer to the intend than this `TOP(1)` construction

Comment: Thank you very much! Not sure why it was down voted so much but hey, you understood my issue and it is working! It just needed the "WHERE dt1.[Name] = dt.[Name]" part :)

Comment: I like the sound of MIN() better. I used the TOP(1) method because it was the first result on stackoverflow...